# A neater solution to an interesting question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Just the other day, a discussion with a friend prompted the following question:
There is a beautiful lady who works at the cashier. A person can only see all the way to the front of the queue if they are taller than each person in front of them, and every individual is either strictly taller or strictly shorter than any one else in the queue. Given n such people, what is the expected number of people who get to admire the beautiful lady at a given moment?

The solution I worked out is not particularly neat, and hence I have only determined the individual probabilities for each m able to see the woman, but not the expected number. It is also not of particularly satisfactory form.

It is as follows:

$\Bbb P\ (\ number \ able\ to \ see =m) = 
\frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{k_2=m-1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k_2}( 
\sum_{k_3=m-2}^{k_2-1}\frac{1}{k_3}(...
(\sum_{k_m=1}^{k_{m-1}-1}\frac{1}{k_m})...)) $

The subscript of $k_i$ corresponds to the tallest person in front of the $k_{i-1}$th tallest person. The value of $k_i$ denotes the number of people in front of the $k_{i-1}$th tallest person, and hence $\frac{1}{k_i}$ denotes the probability that that $k_i$th person is in any particular position.

---

Edit:
Given user49640's suggestion, I include a recursive expression of the above solution for $\Bbb P_n$. n denotes the number of people in the queue, and m denotes the number of people who can see to the front.

$\Bbb P_n\ (no. =m) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\Bbb P_k\ (no. = m-1) $

Comment: Could anyone verify if the probability I give is correct in the first place? Or give a neater form for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectation is $\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k$, where $a_k$ is the probability that the $k$th person in line can see the cashier. And that probability, of course, is $1/k$.

(Let $X_k$ be equal to $1$ when the $k$th person in line can see the cashier, and zero otherwise. We have $E\left(\sum X_k\right) = \sum E(X_k)$. Although the variables $X_k$ are independent, you don't need to know this to apply the formula.)

Comment: "First person"?  You mean $k$th person surely?

Comment: @David Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user49640 Ah yes... that's brilliant. I wonder if there's a nice solution for each probability, however.

Comment: You mean, the probability that the $k$th person in line can see the cashier?

Comment: To put in some extra words as to why the probabilty is 1/k, given any arrangement, the probability that the tallest among the first k people at the front is at position k is 1/k

Comment: @user49640 no, the probabilty that m people can see the cashier

Comment: That's a good question. It seems to me to be more complicated than the expectation question. You can probably write down a recurrence relation for the function $p(n,m)$ that gives the required probability.

Comment: @user49640      Yes, I hope someone comes along either with a better solution than mine or verifies it as the best possible form of an answer. Btw, thank you very much for the help. I should really keep this trick - using linearity of expectation - in mind from now on...

Comment: At present the problem statement refers to expectation. I think that now that you've had an answer, the normal thing to do on this site would be to ask a new question in this situation, despite the fact that it is similar to this one.

Comment: For those who want to have a go, part 2 is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221803/a-neater-solution-to-an-interesting-question-part-2